# Detect if a user refunded a 'consumable' in app purchase item (Apple app store in app purchase system)

Tags: ios, storekit, receipt-validation

I read so far online that the only way to detect if a user cancelled an in app purchase is by using the receipt data that I get from the user's iPhone and check if the cancellation_date exists in there for that item, but as far as I know, this field is only to be found on auto-renewable subscription items.

(At least to what I read online on every post I found that talks about in app purchase, no mention to consumables at all.)

Because they are always stored in the receipt data, while consumable items, are stored in the receipt data until the app itself finishes the transaction, once thats done, the purchase transaction for that item is gone forever from the receipt data after the finish process on the iPhone.

So my question is, if a user requested to cancel an in app purchase from Apple, which is a consumable item, do I also get back that same item transaction in the receipt data WITH the cancellation_date field in it?

I've never seen anyone confirm this.

It would be nice if someone can provide a receipt-data base64 string with cancellation_date example in it (if that's legal to do tho).

Comment: This is the question of the age!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/handling_refund_notifications
Apple has provided a solution finally in 2020!!

Answer (score 3):

A year ago I had the same question as you and I have found [this thread](https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase/issues/47) where author said that Apple has not added a way to detect canceled purchases. I'm still living with that as it is.

The best way to know it is [contacting Apple technical support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/technical/), each account has 2 request/year, so I recommend you to write there.

Hope you will find the answer and tell us about the result.

Comment: that seems to be the size of it, Nosov ...............................  :O  tough one!

Comment: note that @revo has pointed to .. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/257212#197209.   as revo says "So, a year later, and still no solution. I asked the same question on Apple developer forums...."