# Refund in Consumable- In app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented consumable in-app purchase in my application. But the confusion I have is that, can the users ask for refund once they have made a purchase ? And if the refund is granted by Apple, then will the amount be deducted from the developer's account ?

Also, if a user successfully gets a refund, is there any case that I know that he has cancelled the feature. Can I get it from the user's receipt?

Comment: Here's a big BOUNTY on the same question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655893/detect-if-a-user-refunded-a-consumable-in-app-purchase-item-apple-app-store-i

Answer (score 1):

It's generally very difficult for your customers to get refund. Apple doesn't give it out easily, your customers must have very strong reasons. Excuse such as "*I don't like this app*" will not grant any refund. Several my users had asked for refund, but they never succeed.

If the refund is indeed granted, it will be deducted from your account because Apple wouldn't cover the money. Apple won't notify you for the refund.

As long as you are not scamming your users into buying your in-app purchases, you shouldn't expect any refund issue.

Comment: But I have read at multiple places , that the excuse like "Accidentally purchased by a child " might be accepted and the user can get his refund. However , I have not found any official documentation regarding the same.

Comment: @Sumera It's a valid excuse but app-store now requires a password like every 15 minute (you need to double check). Unless it's a very significant amount, and affect many users on the same app, Apple doesn't care.

Comment: @Sumera There is no reason for you to worry. If it's not your sales, then you shouldn't get credit. Are you trying to make dirty tricks in your app? And worry you wouldn't get the money after being reported? Don't do it, you will be banned.

Comment: No dirty tricks in the application to make money. Just a normal flow with extra features for the user.

Comment: "It's generally very difficult for your customers to get refund."  This is wrong.  For IAP, consumers just say "my child did it within the 15 minutes" or "the feature was broken".  Ask any developer who works on high-volume apps: there will be a stream of reversed IAP purchases.